# Go file exchange via TCP problems

Tags: file, go, tcp, io, infinite-loop

Idea. Have tcp server and client. On client writing info about file and file contents to to tcp connection. On server reading that data, creating files and want to return errors if any back to client.

On client using fmt.Fprintf(conn, "test.txt\n") for file info and io.Copy(conn, f), where f is file contents

On server using ReadString('\n') for info about file and

```
w := io.MultiWriter(writers...)

    _, err = io.Copy(w, r)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println([]error{err})
    }
```

And all goes well at 1st, but then I ran into problem on server side with io.Copy going into infinite loop trying to read data from client even when there's none. It doesn't understand that it's EOF or anything.

Tried using conn.Read and similar in loop on server side instead of IO.Copy - and got infinite loop again.

```
    w := io.MultiWriter(writers...)

    for {
        input := make([]byte, 1024*4)
        n, err := conn.Read(input)
        if n == 0 || err != nil {
            log.Error(err, "Read error:")
            break
        }
        
        _, err = w.Write(input[0:n])
        if err != nil {
            log.Error(err, "Failed to copy data on server")
            m = m + fmt.Sprintf("failed to copy data on server: %s\n", err)
        }
    }
```

Read some articles and ran into explanation that it's "normal" behaviour for such blocks during server-client exchanges with readers-writers. One of the suggestions was to use timeout for connection reading(but won't work for me, cuz files can be huge and hard to figure out how long is enough)
Another option is sending some STOP-WORD from client to server to break the loop

But I wander if there's some other way(may be I'm missing out some instruments in go) to achieve desired result without infinite loops, time-outs and stop-words.

Comment: io.Copy loops until It reads to the end of the stream or an error is encountered.  The client should end the stream by calling [CloseWrite](https://pkg.go.dev/net#TCPConn.CloseWrite) or [Close](https://pkg.go.dev/net#TCPConn.Close) after copying the file to the connection.

Comment: CloseWrite worked perfect. Thank you.